# why does $4n-1$ specifies index of a set?

Tags: induction

Hi I'm following a course on mathematical induction, and I found something that doesn't quite make sense to me

The professor gave os this statement: $$3+7+11+\cdots+(4n-1) = n(2n+1)$$

then he goes straight on to test this with $n=1$, and goes straight to $$3 = n(2n+1)$$

and in the case where $n=2$, he simply includes two numbers in the sets $$3 + 7= n(2n+1)$$
So here n is simply the amount of numbers that are included on the left side of the equal sign.
But how is this the case? it seems to me that $3+7+11+\cdots+(4n-1)$ should be $3+7+11*(4n-1)$ which would just output some number

What am I not understanding?

Comment: For $n=1$ we have $n(2n+1)=3$, so far so good?

Comment: It is not $3+7+11\times (4n-1)$, it is $3+7+11+\dots+(4n-1)$.  This is just shorthand for writing $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(4k-1)$.  That is to say when $n$ is $1$ that would be $3$.  When $n$ is $2$ it would be $3+7$.  When $n$ is $3$ it would be $3+7+11$.  When $n$ is $4$ it would be $3+7+11+15$.  In general, for $n$ in general you have the sum of the first $n$ positive numbers which are one less than a multiple of four.

Comment: It must be shown here that $\sum_{k=1}^n(4k-1)=n(2n+1)$ for every positive integer $n$. Is that clear to you?

Comment: The dots there simply mean that the pattern is the same and can be filled in by your own mind, but keeping in mind that for small enough $n$, the pattern can end early, and even earlier than what you might expect from the terms visible.

Comment: dietrich, not really, it shouldnt it be if n=1 then 1(2*1+1)?

Comment: @s3j80 there is no difference.  If $\color{blue}{n}=\color{blue}{1}$ then $\color{blue}{n}(2\cdot \color{blue}{n}+1)$ is the same as $\color{blue}{1}(2\cdot \color{blue}{1}+1)$, both of which equal $3$.

Comment: and if (2n+1) is the way incrementation is made, then shouldnt the incrementation of the three first elements depend on n?

Comment: Let's back up a bit then... Do you understand that when I write $1+2+3+\dots+10$ that this is shorthand for $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10$?  Do you understand then what $1+2+3+\dots+10000$ means and why writing it with dots is preferable to writing out all ten-thousand terms in the sum?

Comment: yes yes, completely. does this mean that (4n-1) is simply the end of the sequence?

Comment: Yes... that's all that is going on here.  $3+7+11+\dots+(4n-1)$ is a sum with $n$ summands (*the individual terms being summed*) whose first term is $3$, whose terms increase by $4$ each time, and whose last term is $4n-1$.  (*Noting that in the case that $n=1$ the first term and the last term are one and the same*).

Comment: this makes sense, I can see the pattern in how the numbers get larger, but i dont see why if n=1, then we act like 7 and 11 doesnt exist. wouldnt it just mean the set would end in 3?

Comment: When $n=1$ we have the first term is $3$, the last term is $(4\cdot 1 -1)$ which is also $3$... and so yes, when $n=1$ there being only one term in the sum that would correspond to the sum $3$ with nothing else added to it.  Yes, that means we "pretend like 7 and 11 don't exist" because they *don't*.  They were only written in the original expression so that the pattern is easier to spot that the terms grow by $4$ each time.  You start with $3$, and until you are done, you add the next term one less than a multiple of four until you reach $4n-1$ which happens right away for $n=1$.